# Set homepage from theme's layout

Tags: magento, layout

I am trying to set a CMS homepage via a theme's `local.xml` layout update file in the `<cms_index_index>` node. I swear I've seen functions to change the store configuration temporarily within a layout node (but maybe I dreamt it), but I'm having trouble finding the layout function in classes like `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and its children classes.

For reference, I've checked in `Mage_Cms_IndexController` and found the function which renders the homepage:

```
public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_HOME_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultIndex');
    }
}
```

Or, am I doing this completely the wrong way? What would be best practice for a problem like this? I do not want to add a store view for the new theme, as the new theme is for mobile platforms and requires the same settings from the store view. Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the purpose in using this approach aot the standard method of **System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages**?

Comment: The reason is a store view cannot have multiple 'CMS Home Page' settings as far as I can tell. We have a single store view with two different themes, and need to set the homepage dependant on the current theme being used.

Comment: In the same way that a store has only one `web/default/cms_home_page` value, it has only one theme. Therefore I assume you are either switching themes programmatically (including via design change) *or* you are switching themes manually and want to automatically have the content switch. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The layout configuration is not invoked until after checks occur to see if there is a valid page which has been specified; because these checks fail, the Default router will match and (by default) the application will display the 404 page.